# How to interpret these probabilities?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, intuition, binomial-distribution

I'm working on the following problem taken from Casella and Berger's book on Statistical Inference:

[image]

I understand their view and could answer the whole problem as the suggested solution, but I rather disagree with the view exposed in item a). I understand that we should visualize the problem of having 5 sets of twins in a class of 60 people as having 10 (not 5) successes with the probability of 1/90 for each of them.

This is motivated by the statement that says that the probability of a twin birth is around 1/90. So, if a person is chosen randomly in the population, its chance of being a twin is 1/90. But if, for a given set of twin brothers, one of them goes to one school and the other one goes to another school these would not count as a "success" for our exercise, although they happen to be twins!!!

Can anyone explain me how this works? Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the crux of your question... is the central point that you're worried about the possibility that there might be twins who attend different schools?

Comment: I'm not sure I buy their model.  They'd be correct if "being a twin" was some individual trait.  In that case, assuming independence of all the events would be a sensible starting point.  But "being a twin" is hardly independent of the other kids, that's kind of the whole point.  We can only have evenly many twins (barring low probability events, of course).

Comment: I'd do the computation recursively.  Ignoring triplets and such.   Let $P(k,n)$ be the probability that there are exactly (or at least) $n$ twin pairs amongst $k$, then $P(k,n)=(1-p)\times P(k-1,n)+p\times P(k-2,n-1)$.  Easy to do mechanically.  (note:  here $p$ denotes the probability that a randomly selected child is part of a twin pair, so $p=\frac  1{90}$ in the given situation).

Comment: If you are interested in the problem, I'd suggest working it out carefully.  Maybe there is some normal approximation that makes things simpler.  For small samples, though, my point is definitely real.  If, say, you had $2$ kids then the probability that they were both part of a twin pair is $\frac 1{90}$, not $\frac 2{90}-\frac 1{90^2}$.  About half, in other words.

Comment: As an alternate method, you might imagine that the school takes every child born in a certain time window.  That lets you think about births, not kids.  So, to get exactly $60$ kids you might have had $60$ single births, or $59$ singles and one set of twins, etc.  I don't like this because there is no a priori way to set the probability of having had exactly $N$ births.  It would be interesting to know, for example, whether $60$ was the expected number of births in the window or not.

Comment: I'm not surprised that you're surprised by the Casella-Berger quote. The whole point is that it is superficially surprising. Suggest you approach their argument with an open mind, supposing that they they might actually know what they're talking about. (In fact, they do. But from what you say, I'd want you to think some more before engaging in a discussion.) // Similar paradoxes: It's 'almost impossible' for any 1 person to win a lottery. But many lotteries are won by someone. If I look out window over busy ave, what are chances 1st car has 476 at end of license nr? Tiny.  But just happened.

Comment: I agree @BruceET!